# How do I use a for loop to determine whether integers are present in a text file?

Tags: python, file, for-loop

I am dealing with a folder that contains 100 different text files containing 2 numbers on separate lines. I am trying to write a function that takes a list (seq) and determines whether each corresponding number is present in the previous numbers textfile.

For example, given [5, 25, 12] the function should first go to page 5 of the textfile and determine if 25 is present on that page, if it is then the program should go to page 25 and determine whether 12 is present or not. If it is present then the function should return true, otherwise false. Currently, my function only returns false.

This is what I have so far. I am not permitted to use readline/readlines.

```
def is_valid_page_sequence(seq):
    for i in seq:
        page_name='page'+str(i)+'.txt'
        page=open(folder+page_name, 'r')
        next_page=list(page.read())
        if i!=int(next_page[0]) and i!=int(next_page[1]):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: `list(page.read())` makes a list of _each individual character_ in the file, which probably isn't what you wanted.  i.e. if the file contains `Hey 12`, the list would be `['H', 'e', 'y', ' ', '1', '2']`

Comment: `if str(i) in page.read():`

Comment: You say it should check if a number "is present", but you seem to only be checking if it's the first or second character (or probably word)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'in' method like for eg.

```
if 25 in next_page:
```

Comment: This won't work because `next_page` is a list of individual characters.  It's the right concept, though.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

folder = './files'


def is_valid_page_sequence(seq):
    for prev, number in zip(seq, seq[1:]):
        with open(str(Path(folder) / f'page{prev}.txt')) as f:
            if str(number) not in f.read().split():
                return False
    return True


print(is_valid_page_sequence([5, 25, 12]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_valid_page_sequence(seq):

if(len(seq)>1):
    page_name='page'+seq[0]+'.txt'
    page=open(folder+page_name, 'r')
    next_page=page.read()
    for i in seq[1:]:
        if str(i) in next_page:
            is_valid_page_sequence(seq[1:])
        else:
            return False    

return True
```

either I understood your point of view or I'm completely wrong there is nothing in between